# Add after method with plugin on underscore methods

Tags: magento2, plugin

I try to add plugin after a method that start with underscore like this : "_myMethod".

My plugin work, I can add method after normal method, but I can't add my method after the one with " _ " before name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 `plugins` cannot be used with any of the following,

- Objects that are instantiated before `Magento\Framework\Interception` is 
  bootstrapped
- Final methods
- Final classes
- Any class that contains at least one final public method
- Non-public methods (**I think you are using private method**)
- Static methods
- __construct
- Virtual types

You can read more about plugin from below link,

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 6):

Neither of these answers actually address the issue in the title: *how to define an interceptor for a method which name begins with an underscore*; although the assumption that the developer is likely to be trying to intercept a protected/private method, you sometimes stumble upon someone else's code that does't follow such convention.

On Magento 2.3.1 it works by simply prefixing `after` to the method name like in:

```
public function _doFoo(...)

public function after_doFoo(...)
```

In order to validate a new Plugin definition, I found this code useful

```
$pluginValidator = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\InterfaceValidator::class);
$pluginValidator->validate(FooPlugin::class, Foo::class);
```

You can see the internals of how the method names are being mapped in `\Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\InterfaceValidator::getOriginMethodName`

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using plugins for private or protected methods. As plugins only work for public methods.

By convention in Magento functions & variables that start with an underscore indicate that the variable or function is protected or private, hence why I am assuming you are trying to plugin into a private or protected method.

> A plugin, or interceptor, is a class that modifies the behavior of public class functions by intercepting a function call and running code before, after, or around that function call [.. readmore](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Oh didn't knew that, yes the method is private, thanks for answer !